# Sharing ECR repository within AWS organiztion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

How can I share a repository in AWS ECR with all other accounts in organization? From what I have read here and elswere it seems like resource based permissions are the way to go. Namely it is suggested to add aws:PrincipalOrgID condition to a resource. However, when I use Account-A within organization to share the resource I still do not see that resource appearing in private repositories list in Account-B of the same organization. At this point I have exousted all the ideas and just don't understand how to move forward. I am very new to AWS.

Here is how my private repository is configured

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ReadonlyAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:ListImages"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-orgniztion"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/sharing-amazon-ecr-repositories-with-multiple-accounts-using-aws-organizations/) post you can use

```json
"Condition": {
    "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
       "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths":["o-xxxxxxxxxx/r-xxxx/ou-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/*"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially this is the same except also includes finer detalisation of who get to access the resource, in this case all users in ou-xxxx-xxxxxxxx group. I can't use it like this because I'm waiting for my manager to provide me access rights to create this "ou-xxxx-xxxxxxxx" group in our organization. But I really doubt it will make a difference

Comment: While using `aws:PrincipalOrgID` you will share resources will all organization but with `aws:PrincipalOrgPaths` you can give this permission only `Developers` Group, not `Financial` Group

Comment: I think that is exactly what I said :)